# Difference between Session.Clear() vs. Session.Contents.Clear()

Tags: asp.net

What is difference between Session.Clear() vs. Session.Contents.Clear()?

I want to clear all the Session variables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to reflector there is **no difference**. `Session.Contents` returns the `Session` object itself.